# select unique rows containing maximum difference between column IDs

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, tidyverse

I have a large set of data frames with multiple identical row names and but each with a different value for specific column IDs. I want to extract unique rows with the largest difference for two columns IDs.

For example, here is a sample data

```
    seqname             source           start  end Name    score
    chr08:37848-37905   PRINTS           24     37  AAA     1.40E-05
    chr08:37848-37905   PANTHER          1      57  AAA     1.10E-15
    chr08:37848-37905   SUPERFAMILY      3      57  AAA     6.80E-13
    chr08:37848-37905   Gene3D           1      57  AAA     6.40E-17
    chr05:55489-55514   Pfam             2      23  BBB     7.30E-07
    chr05:55489-55514   Gene3D           1      25  BBB     7.10E-07
    chr05:55489-55514   ProSiteProfiles  1      25  BBB     9.683545
    chr05:55489-55514   SUPERFAMILY      2      24  BBB     1.23E-06
```

I want to get all the columns of unique rows that have minimum **start** and max **end** values the unique rows. The output looks like

```
seqname             source           start  end   Name    score
chr08:37848-37905   Gene3D           1      57    AAA     6.40E-17
chr05:55489-55514   Gene3D           1      25    BBB    7.10E-07
```

group_by results only for selected the summarised IDs but I could not able to figure to keep rows with those selected values

```
     data %>% dplyr::group_by(seqname) %>% 
        summarize(start=min(start), end=max(end))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your example - why is Gene3D chosen over PANTHER for the first group? Their start and end values are identical?

Comment: In the first group, Gene3D is showing the lowest score hit which is the p-value for its occurrence and is the one I am interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close -  you just need to use `filter` rather than `summarize`. Like so:

```
 data %>% dplyr::group_by(seqname) %>% 
    filter(start==min(start), end==max(end))
```

This assumes that there is exactly one row that has both the minimum start and the maximum end for each `seqname`. If there is more than one they will both be returned. If different rows have the max and the min, then none of them will be returned.

If you want the row with the min start and the row with the max end, even if they are different rows, use this for the filter

```
    summarize(start==min(start) | end==max(end))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @John Paul. It worked perfectly.  I added score==min(score) in the filter function to pick up the lowest value which is the one I am looking for.